# SWIG: Mapping an array of a typedef

Tags: c++, ruby, linux, pointers, swig

I'm using SWIG to create a Ruby Wrapper for some C++ classes. This is the signature of the C++ method which is giving me trouble:

```
virtual LogP wordProb(VocabIndex word, const VocabIndex *context);
```

This is the definition of VocabIndex:

```
#ifdef USE_SHORT_VOCAB
typedef unsigned short  VocabIndex;
#else
typedef unsigned int    VocabIndex;
#endif
```

This is the way I'm calling it from a Ruby script:

```
index = 8
context = [index]
puts ngram.wordProb(index, context)
```

This is the error I'm getting when I run my script:

```
ngram.rb:26:in `wordProb': Expected argument 2 of type VocabIndex const *, but got Array [8] (TypeError)
    in SWIG method 'wordProb'
    from ngram.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

**My attempted solution**:

After reading the [docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Ruby_nn32) (yes, I'm using SWIG 2.0), I tried this in my .i file:

```
%module rubylm

%{
#include "srilm-1.7.1/lm/src/Ngram.h"
%}

%include "srilm-1.7.1/lm/src/Counts.h"
%include "srilm-1.7.1/lm/src/Ngram.h"
%include "typemaps.i"

virtual LogP Ngram::wordProb(VocabIndex word, const VocabIndex *INPUT);
```

The swig command ran fine, but when I tried to build the wrapper library, I got this:

```
NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx:148:17: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <tcl.h>
```

So I fired up a terminal (this is an Ubuntu box) and ran:

```
sudo apt-get install tcl-dev
```

This installed tcl 8.6, which placed its header files in the `/usr/include/tcl8.6` directory. So I added that include directory in the Makefile line which builds NgramWrapper_wrap.o:

```
NgramWrapper_wrap.o: NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx -I $(RUBY_SRC) -I $(MISC_INCLUDE) -I $(DSTRUCT_INCLUDE) -I /usr/include/tcl8.6
```

However, I'm still getting build errors. And here's where I got stumped:

```
NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx:10812:34: error: ‘RARRAY_LEN’ was not declared in this scope
     int size = RARRAY_LEN(objv[3]); 
                                  ^
NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx:10816:5: error: ‘VALUE’ was not declared in this scope
     VALUE *ptr = RARRAY_PTR(objv[3]);
     ^
NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx:10816:12: error: ‘ptr’ was not declared in this scope
     VALUE *ptr = RARRAY_PTR(objv[3]);
            ^
NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx:10816:36: error: ‘RARRAY_PTR’ was not declared in this scope
     VALUE *ptr = RARRAY_PTR(objv[3]);
                                    ^
NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx:10819:35: error: ‘StringValuePtr’ was not declared in this scope
       arg3[i]= StringValuePtr(*ptr); 
                                   ^
NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx: In function ‘int _wrap_NgramCountWrapper_run(ClientData, Tcl_Interp*, int, Tcl_Obj* const*)’:
NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx:10908:34: error: ‘RARRAY_LEN’ was not declared in this scope
     int size = RARRAY_LEN(objv[3]); 
                                  ^
NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx:10912:5: error: ‘VALUE’ was not declared in this scope
     VALUE *ptr = RARRAY_PTR(objv[3]);
     ^
NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx:10912:12: error: ‘ptr’ was not declared in this scope
     VALUE *ptr = RARRAY_PTR(objv[3]);
            ^
NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx:10912:36: error: ‘RARRAY_PTR’ was not declared in this scope
     VALUE *ptr = RARRAY_PTR(objv[3]);
                                    ^
NgramWrapper_wrap.cxx:10915:35: error: ‘StringValuePtr’ was not declared in this scope
       arg3[i]= StringValuePtr(*ptr);
```

All I can think of is some version mismatch between Ruby, Swig and Tcl. But how can I know which Tcl version to use? I scoured the docs to no avail...

Comment: Carrays.i is the quick solution: http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Library.html#Library_carrays with more knowledge of ruby than I have you could do something smarter.

Comment: If I try to use carrays.i, I get the same build errors as when I try to use typemaps.i. There's something wrong in my Ruby-Swig-Tcl combo. All I can come up with now is downgrading Tcl. Gonna try that.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.

I just did the following

vocal.i

```
%module rubylm

%{
#include "Ngram.h"
%}

%include "Ngram.h"
%include "typemaps.i"

virtual LogP Ngram::wordProb(VocabIndex word, const VocabIndex *INPUT);
```

Ngram.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef USE_SHORT_VOCAB
typedef unsigned short  VocabIndex;
#else
typedef unsigned int    VocabIndex;
#endif

typedef int LogP;

class NGram {
 public:
  LogP wordProb(VocabIndex word, const VocabIndex *context);
};
```

Command executed

`swig2.0 -ruby -c++ vocal.i`

followed by

`g++ -c vocal_wrap.cxx  -I/usr/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.1.0`

without any errors. Have you forgot the -c++ option and why do you need tcl.h

Comment: The Tcl dependency appears when I %include `typemaps.i` or `carrays.i`. If I look at the generated code, right at the beginning there's this line: `#define SWIGTCL`.
The -c++ option was always there, I'm using a Makefile.
By the way, you're using ruby 2.1.0, and I'm using 1.9.3. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Maybe. I think I would go through the included headers and see if there is some missing defines. Remember SWIG does not recurse headers. It could also be that the wrong typemaps.i is included.

Comment: @dario_ramos I get no `#define SWIGTCL` in my generated code. I think maybe the `typemaps.i` or `carrays.i` which gets included are the wrong ones. You are wrapping code for Ruby

Comment: Is there a way for me to check that? Or maybe use an absolute path in the %include directive... I'll try that

Comment: Also verify that the argument -ruby is passed to SWIG and not -tcl. Check also in the swig directories that the `typemaps.i` in the ruby folder is correct.